# What is causing IE 8 to pause on Site load?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, load-time

Hey guys, I am trying to see if any of you have experience the same thing I am with Internet Explorer 8.  When I go to load a site I built, I can see the whole page is loaded but it pauses for like 8 seconds before you can scroll or move.  Once it is done pausing, it is fine to scroll around but if you click on a different page same thing happens again.  This does not happen in any other browsers.

So I tried a few things like completely disabling JS to see if something in there is causing it and it still does the same thing.  So at this point, I am not sure if it is because of a certain advanced CSS statement or something causing this issue.

*Note* it works fine surfing other sites...

Any idea?

Comment: It could be any number of things; can you give us a link to the site, or is it private at the moment?

Comment: Yes I realize it could be anything at this moment but just checking if anyone has similar issues before and found a solution. The site is currently on localhost so nothing to show at this moment.